# Is it wise to change the standard "Login / Sign In" text to something else?

Tags: forms, terminology, interface

I'm developing a mobile app for a client, and he keeps suggesting that instead of the conventional wording "Login" or "Sign In", we should use "Get Started" instead.

I'm worried that the users might not recognise it as the login button and they might think it's a button which will let them skip logging in.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: get started usually used at tutorials ,in my opinion get started should be  used once the user authenticates and explores the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question I would ask is why does he suggest using this? I find most fears about 'Users won't recognise ...' are unfounded: in both cases you have a form and a button; there is a good visual association between the two and it's just the wording that has changed, so users are likely to make the association. 'Sign in' has the benefit of being conventional, but if your brand / style is in keeping with the more informal 'Get started' (and your client has a good rationale), why not?

Answer (score 1):

As @Peter has already said, most users will probably recognize the pattern regardless of what text it contains but you could always test out the theory by printing out a bunch of mockups with your text, his text and no text, and then just spend an afternoon in a coffee shop or shopping mall asking people to look at them at random and tell you where they'd click to log in.

Comment: You could probably also use https://usabilityhub.com/ for some semi automated testing